# Develop internet radio listener client using iceast server

Tags: c, icecast, internet-radio

I am setting up an internet radio listener client in C using Icecast protocol. I am a beginner. How can i connect to icecast?
How to decode the audio stream?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend to look at other players, but essentially you have *two* components:

- obtain the stream
- decode the stream and send it to an audio device

For the first I'd strongly recommend to use an established HTTP library like [cURL](https://curl.haxx.se/), as even if you need to set custom headers for legacy stream formats, you can easily do this.

For the latter it's also not particularly hard, although if you want to handle legacy stream formats (ICY/Shoutcast type streams with multiplexed metadata) then you need to do additional work.

The primary supported Icecast stream formats are using the [Ogg](https://xiph.org/ogg/) container and there is *libOgg* to handle this. If you want to be able to handle WebM-audio, you'll also need to handle WebM/MKV/EBML as the container and I'd expect there to be a library.

This is followed by actually decoding the data to uncompressed audio that can be sent to the sound system of your OS. This can be codec implementations in libopus, libvorbis or others.

The last two steps can also be achieved by enlisting various libraries like libffmpeg or gstreamer. This is far more common than implementing things from scratch. Some even choose to have the HTTP(S) part done by a player library.

Note that I didn't cover legacy formats like MP3 or raw AAC above, but things are somewhat similar for those.

Comment: Is there any aac decoder other than faad? @TBR

Comment: yes, there are _many_ decoders. Your choice will depend on many factors like operating system, available libraries, licensing. - I'm not familiar with AAC though. I concentrate on Opus and Vorbis.

Comment: how to decode using vorbis? what is the difference between ogg and vorbis

Comment: [Ogg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ogg) is a [container format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_container_format) and [Vorbis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vorbis) and [Opus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opus_(audio_format)) are [audio codecs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_coding_format). Use libogg and libvorbis or libopus for decoding.

Comment: I am trying to decode using libvorbis but getting segmentation fault from ov_open_callbacks. I am passing data through a buffer.